# IsChecked is set to false

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

After searching and trying several options over the last week, I can't seem to find what I am looking for; maybe someone here can help. While reading through this, please keep in mind that I am attempting to utilize MVVM as strictly as possible, though I am relatively new to WPF. As a side note, I am using Mahapps.Metro to style my window and controls, found [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro).

I have an XML file that my application uses for configuration (I cannot use the app.config file because the application cannot install on the users' systems). The application will look for this file at start-up and if it does not find the file, it will create it. Below is a snippet of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<prefRoot>
  <tabReport>
    <cbCritical>True</cbCritical>
  </tabReport>
```

I reference the `XML` file in my `Window.Resources:`

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlConfig"
                         Source="%appdata%\Vulnerator\Vulnerator_Config.xml"
                         XPath="prefRoot"
                         IsAsynchronous="False"
                         IsInitialLoadEnabled="True"/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

And utilize this as the `DataContext` for my `MainWindow:`

```
<Controls:MetroWindow DataContext="{DynamicResource XmlConfig}">
```

Next, I set up a "string-to-bool" converter:

```
class StringToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            bool? isChecked = (bool?)value;
            return isChecked;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string isChecked = value.ToString();
            return isChecked;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Finally, I bind `IsChecked` to the appropriate `XPath:`

```
<Checkbox x:Name="cbCritical"
          Content="Critical"
          IsChecked="{Binding XPath=//tabReport/cbCritical, 
                      Converter={StaticResource StringToBool}}" />
```

After all of this, the applciation loads, but `IsChecked` is set to `false`... Any and all ideas would be helpful here; thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your methods supposed to return an object instead of a direct bool or string?

Comment: Have you included the converter in your resources section?

Comment: How is an application level converter for your XML bool to string MVVM? Your application shouldn't know anything about how your data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your converter would be better off to not return null but `false` upon default. If the conversion fails for whatever reason, return an actual value.
2. The code `(bool?)value` will not convert a string to a Boolean. Change it to:

`return (value.ToLower() == "true")`.